# titanium appcelerator window small

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In appcelerator I'm trying to open a window with this code

```
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            backgroundColor: '#616161',
            color: 'blue',
            exitOnClose: true,
            height: 1000,
            navBarHidden: true,
            width:Ti.UI.FILL,
            _moving: false,
            _startx: 0,
            _endx: 0,
            top:0,
            left:0
       });
```

but the window in iphone shrinks strangely with status bar to about 80% of screen...
I tried in simulator and in device and in both places it keeps appearing 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq60S.png)

Any ideas why it might happen? 
ios 9.3 and appcelerator sdk 5.2.1GA
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have correct `splash` image for your device or simulator , you can use this awesome tool  [TiCons](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/) , it will generate all `splash` , `icon` and `assets` sizes  for you

Answer (score 3):

I have had this issue in the past and for me it was not having the right sized splash screen, and that caused the app run in the smaller iphone 4 size.  Make sure you have all these sizes in you project

iPhone 4/4S
Splash screen
640 x 960
72
Default@2x.png

iPhone 5/5C/5S
iPod touch 5th generation
Splash screen
640 x 1136
72
Default-568h@2x.png

iPhone 6
Splash screen
750 x 1334
72
Default-667h@2x.png

iPhone 6 Plus landscape
Splash screen
2208 x 1242
72
Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png

iPhone 6 Plus portrait
Splash screen
1242 x 2208
72
Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png

I got this info from and more details can be found [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens)